# Rewriting this url for WHMCS using HTACCESS?

Tags: .htaccess, whmcs

I have this url:

```
/index.php?m=mymodule&action=overview
```

I instead want this:

```
/mymodule/overview
```

Or even better, add another path prior:

```
/clientarea/mymodule/overview
```

Anyone know how to set up a rule in htaccess for this?

I had a look at how Drupal does something similar, but I don't think it helps my case. With drupal, you can open /bla/foo/whatever and it will effectively pass it as parameters to index.php. That is exactly what I am trying to do. So here's what drupal does:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

But that doesn't help me. I need something that specifically maps:

```
/mymodule/overview
```

to

```
/index.php?m=mymodule&action=overview
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I am close with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %2index.php?m=$0&action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If I access "/mymodule/overview" then query string parameter m = /mymodule/overview and not just mymodule. And action is blank. How do I =make it split "/mymodule/overview" into "mymodule" and "overview" ?

Comment: I know this post is old but I am in need of the same thing. What was your final solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a  helpful Answer!!

```
#FROM /mymodule/overview 
#TO /index.php?m=mymodule&action=overview
#QAS QueryString Append

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Not Directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Not file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Not Link ?? No Need.
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^((\w+)\/)((\w+)\/*)(.*)$ index.php?m=$2&action=$4&plah=$5 [QSA,L]
```

TEST:

```
mymodule/overview/do/some/thing --> match; plah=do/some/thing
mymodule/overview/do/some/thing/ --> match; plah=do/some/thing/
mymodule/overview/ --> match; plah is empty
mymodule/overview --> match; plah is empty
mymodule/ --> Not match
mymodule  --> Not match
```

I recommend to use a prefix `m` for example, for your modules; to prevent redirecting other URLs to your modules.
`/m/mymodule/overview`
Then use:
`^m\/((\w+)\/)((\w+)\/*)(.*)$`

On Online Regular Expression Tester:
https://regex101.com/r/TSvl9n/2